# Rails: DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive this warning when running my specs.  Is there a best practice for generating a secret_key_base, or will any string suffice (with regard to security concerns)?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You propably upgraded to Rails 4 from a 3.x or a previous version.

First generate a random secret key value:

```
$ bundle exec rake secret
```

Then take that value and put it in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`:

```
YourApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'your-secret'
```

replacing `YourApp` with the name of your application.

The reason for this is explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#action-pack).

Also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml

Comment: But I don't have `secret_token.rb` at `config/initializers/secret_token.rb:` what should I do because I am getting error this `You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.` What can I do to resolve lt.

Comment: Look at `config/secrets.yml` and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml

Comment: In case anyone is curious, [`rake secret`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d20f7b043a537b57ff4a7911f65de2fb7b7aea7d/railties/lib/rails/tasks/misc.rake#L1-L5) is just (currently) doing `puts SecureRandom.hex(64)`

Comment: Does this still need to be done in `secret_token.rb`? I'm getting mixed information about `secrets.yml`

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood it can be done either way. You don't have to implement `secrets.yml` but it now comes stock with new Rails 4(.2+?) installations and if you use that you would get rid of the `secret_token.rb` file

Comment: I didn't add secret_key_base to that file, just secret_token. That got it to work for me. Actually, it just loads the token from the env.

Comment: Does anything break if you set 

<kbd>YourApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = SecureRandom.hex(64)</kbd>

Comment: @KrisRobison yes, every time your application is restarted all of the previously generated cookies will be invalid thus logging out all your users.

Comment: FYI - You may already have `secret_token` set in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`. You'll continue to get the deprecation warning until you set `secret_key_base`. This can affect users as the newly signed cookies will not be backwards compatible with older cookies. [More info here.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#action-pack)

Comment: Simplified as `Rails.application.config.secret_key_base = 'your-secret'`

Answer (score 6):

As of 4.1, you need to use the `config/secrets.yml` file. This is discussed in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml .

Comment: Actually, in the link, it says "If you want to use the new secrets.yml convention to store your application's secrets..."  I don't see anything that says you *need* to.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to create a secret_token.rb file in the config/initializers directory.

Contents of the file below:

```
YourAppNameHere::Application.config.secret_key_base = #type the key you generated with rake secret here
```

then save the file

```
close your server: 
ctrl c

restart it: rails s
```

You'll now see the basic rails app page you saw in the last chapter (If you're working through Hartl's tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

If you are a total noob like me, remember to put the secret_key_base = 'whatever' inside single quotes.  Just a copy and paste without quotes will throw an error :

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load': C:/Users/Jeff C/documents/rails_proje
cts/first_app/config/initializers/secret_token.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tI
DENTIFIER, expecting $end (SyntaxError)

Comment: That was it. Slightly confusing because `secrets.yml` just expects a sequence of characters after it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue when working on a **Rails 4** application that was upgraded to **Rails 5**.

All I had to do was run the command below to generate a `secret key`:

```
bundle exec rake secret
```

And then I added the secret key to the `config/secret.yml` file:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 21bc6137d0496a2a11f4459a7c7deb4f782d223d41ee328934b2fe7a405a42ec63eb3829db67f0ec6a759e134ba0bb15dc2d01168b64d83efcf8d42b403ac8bd
```