# You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am trying to run my web application I am getting below error on the browser:

```
You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.
```

I don't understand why it comes, and I don't have `secret_token.rb` at `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`. How do I resolve it.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have added the secret token file in the git ignore file. Remove the **`config/initializers/secret_token.rb`** from **`.gitignore`** file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268669/deprecation-warning-you-didnt-set-config-secret-key-base) can help you

Comment: and where is .gitignore file on the system.

Comment: go to the directory where your project is stored and press Ctrl + h...This will list all the hidden files. gitignore is a hidden file

Comment: I have pushed my application on the github and check .gitignore txt file but there is no this type of statement `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` on the .gitignore txt file. how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Check the link provided in the answer

Comment: after running this command `rake secret` on rails command line, `secret_token.rb` is created on the project?

Comment: I have already check that link but I don't have `secret_token.rb` file on the project? where I can update token generated from the command `rake secret`.

Comment: create a secret token.rb file and inside it add this line "Projectname::Application.config.secret_token = ' put your secret token generated by rake secret command here'"....And you are ready to go.