# RubyonRails- You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org, secret-key

I am trying to go to my localhost and I keep getting the following error in my browser:

```
You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config
```

I have looked around and people say that you have to rake the secret key and then put it into `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` but I don't have a `secret_token.rb` file in my folder. I am running ruby version `ruby 2.1.2p9` and rails version **Rails 4.0.8** I am following the tutorial at `railstutorial.org` if that helps on 2.2

Comment: Did you run `rake secret` in your console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret\_key\_base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268669/deprecation-warning-you-didnt-set-config-secret-key-base)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run `rake secret` to generate a new token.

Now create a new file `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` and add the following:

```
MyApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = '<token>'
```

Replace `<token>` with the one you just generated and replace `MyApp` with the actual module name of your app. You can find the module name of your app at the top of `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: The app's name is not in the mentioned file. How else can I find out? Thx

Comment: In newer versions of Rails you can use `Rails.application.config.secret_key_base`

Answer (score 1):

**Rails-5**

In rails-5, create `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`

Add `Rails.application.config.secret_key_base= 'secret_token'`

where `'secret_token' = rake:secret`

Restart the server